# Create new record inside a ClassMap ConvertUsing method

Tags: csvhelper

The case is that I'm parsing a file, that looks something like this.

| Name | Account |
| --- | --- |
| Foo client | 123 |
| Bar client | 456,789 |

In the real data I do some more stuff, to clean up account, etc, but the main point is the `,` in the Account column. I now get an IEnumerable with 2 records, I'd like to get an IEnumerable with 3 records, by splitting records on the comma in the Account column.

Like this.

| Name | Account |
| --- | --- |
| Foo client | 123 |
| Bar client | 456 |
| Bar client | 789 |

Is this possible to achieve through CSV Helper?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```cs
void Main()
{
    using (var sReader = new StringReader("Name,Account\nFoo client,123\nBar client,\"456,789\""))
    using (var csvReader = new CsvHelper.CsvReader(sReader, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture))
    {
        csvReader.Read();
        csvReader.ReadHeader();
        
        var records = new List<Foo>();
        
        while (csvReader.Read())
        {
            var name = csvReader.GetField("Name");
            var account = csvReader.GetField("Account");
            
            var splitAccounts = account.Split(",");
            
            foreach(var item in splitAccounts)
            {
                records.Add(new Foo { Name = name, Account = int.Parse(item)});
            }
            
        }
        records.Dump();
    }
}

public class Foo 
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Account { get; set; }
}
```

**Update:**
Each row is a record, so you really can't create a new record with your `ClassMap` outside of the row.  What you might be able to do is wrap your class in another class that contains a `List<MyClass>` of the records you are trying to create and then combine them back into a single `List<MyClass>`.  If `Account` can be type `string` in `MyClass` you could get away without the separate `MyClassMap` and just let it `AutoMap()` your class.

```cs
void Main()
{
    using (var sReader = new StringReader("Name,Account\nFoo client,123\nBar client,\"456,789\""))
    using (var csvReader = new CsvHelper.CsvReader(sReader, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture))
    {
        csvReader.Configuration.RegisterClassMap<FooMap>();
        csvReader.Configuration.RegisterClassMap<MyClassMap>();
        
        var wrappedRecords = csvReader.GetRecords<Foo>();
        
        var records = wrappedRecords.SelectMany(r => r.Clients).ToList();
        
        records.Dump();
    }
}

public class FooMap : ClassMap<Foo>
{
    public FooMap()
    {
        Map(x => x.Clients).ConvertUsing(x =>
        {
            var records = new List<MyClass>();
            
            var record = x.GetRecord<MyClass>();
            
            var splitAccounts = x.GetField("Account").Split(",");

            foreach (var item in splitAccounts)
            {
                records.Add(new MyClass { Name = record.Name, Account = int.Parse(item) });
            }
            
            return records;
        });
    }
}

public class MyClassMap : ClassMap<MyClass>
{
    public MyClassMap()
    {
        Map(x => x.Name);
    }   
}

public class Foo
{
    public List<MyClass> Clients { get; set; }
}

public class MyClass
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Account { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: That would work, but I failed to mention that I'd like to do the conversion inside the convert stage of the Account column, in the class map that I'm using.

Comment: See if my update gets you closer to what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: Thanks for the effort David. I actually ended up letting CSV Helper do it's thing, which is just parsing lines, and added another cleaning step afterwards, to handle it with some lines of Linq.